# vb.net date of the day after every 24 hours

Tags: vb.net, date, timer, datetimepicker

I have a timer which is to tick after every **86400000seconds** (every 24 hours and therefore every day) to put the new day in a DateTimePicker, **dtPicker1**. Unfortunately, after the timer ticks the result brings the time of the day in addition to the date (for example **2017-03-18 00:00:05**, instead of **2017-03-18**. When I use the messagebox to check the output, I get the date without the time but the next day (after the timer ticks, it adds the time and therefore the code fails.

`'ticks every 86400000 miliseconds (a day)
        dtPicker1.Enabled = True

```
    dtPicker1.Text = ""
    Dim mFmt As String = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dtPicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    dtPicker1.CustomFormat = mFmt


    dtPicker1.Text = ""

    Dim st As Date = Today.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString

    Dim cf As String = Today.AddDays(-1)
    Dim dr As String = cf.Substring(3, 2)
    'MsgBox(dr)
    Dim de As String = cf.Substring(6, 4)
    Dim fg As String = cf.Substring(3, 2)
    Dim ab As String = cf.Substring(0, 2)

    'MsgBox(de & "-" & fg & "-" & ab, vbInformation, "Here you Go")

    dtPicker1.Value = de & "-" & fg & "-" & ab`
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You dont need to convert a `DateTime` type to string to access Day, month, year, hour, min, sec, ms.  Examine the properties of it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use substrings, you can set the value directly as a date.

```
    dtPicker1.Text = ""
    Dim mFmt As String = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dtPicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    dtPicker1.CustomFormat = mFmt
    dtPicker1.Value = Today.AddDays(-1)
```

Comment: I need to pick yesterday's date and with that, I will have to use AddDays(-1).

Comment: So then it would be Today.AddDays(-1).ToString()

Comment: Why are you converting to string?  Just examine the properties of the `DateTime` itself.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Which string are you talking about? Is it **mfmt**, **cf**, **dr**, **de**, **fg**, **ab**? Which datatype will you advice I use? Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: thanks, @obl . dtPicker1.value = Today.AddDays(-1).ToString(yyyy-MM-dd) gave the **time** in addition to the **date**, whereas I need only the date. Thanks for your help as well.